# How to implement sequence number database for each group of users?

Tags: mysql

It's easy to create a database table for storing `sequence` numbers ; but this design is suited for the event when the `sequence` is shared for all users. What I want is to create `sequence` for each **group** of users : this `group` can grow at any time because it's a database table , that is the administrator can create a group at any time and users are assigned to a specific group. So how to implement the `sequence` generation according to a group ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using myisam

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

**Below extracted from above links.**

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a
>   secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the
>   generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>   MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is
>   useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
Which returns:

+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

For your case:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   user_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    group_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,   
     user_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id,user_id)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO mytable (group_id, user_name) VALUES
     (1,'alex'),(1,'jenny'),(2,'baz'),(1,'tim'),(2,'danny'),(3,'joe');


SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY group_id,user_id;
```

Returns:

```
user_id group_id    user_name
1            1          alex
2            1          jenny
3            1          tim
1            2          baz
2            2          danny
1            3          joe
```

Comment: It is not necessary to be MEDIUMINT.